# Need regular expression for first number in string

Tags: regex, google-shopping

i need to exclude the first number of the following string:
DE 199,00;AT 219,99; IT 399,00
In this case i need the 199,00

DE 79,00;AT 99,99; IT 119,00
And here i need 79,00

I have no plan of regex :-( So i hope that i get help here.
Thank you

With the following i get the first "Group" eg DE 199,00

```
^[^;]*
```

But i need just the number

Comment: What regex flavor, can you use [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)? Try e.g. [`^\D*\b([\d,]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/fL62oN/1)

Answer (score 1):

`^[^;]*` -This regex matches any string that does not contain a semicolon (;) including letters.

`\d+(?:,\d{2})` -This regex adheres to a pattern that matches any number of digits (1 or more), followed by an optional group of a comma and two digits.

Edit:
Trying to understand your comment on the answer above. So what you want to do is to find any group beginning with the letters DE followed by a whitespace, string, and semicolon => `/DE\s\D+;/;`
This will give you a group that relates to your `DE 199,00;` and after you have this you can extract the number.

Answer (score 0):

To extract "199,00" from the string "DE 199,00;AT 219,99; IT 399,00" you'd use the regular expression

```
[0-9,]+
```

Comment: with this i get all numbers of the string.

Comment: [Here's an example at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gvNIml/1)